# Binding inside UserControl

Tags: c#, xaml, user-controls, winrt-xaml, uwp

I created a custom UserControl. Following a [blog post](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2013/07/solved-two-way-binding-inside-user.html) my control code-behind looks like this:

```cs
public BasicGeoposition PinGeoposition
{
    get { return (BasicGeoposition) GetValue(PropertyPinGeoposition); }
    set { SetValueDp(PropertyPinGeoposition, value);}
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty PropertyPinGeoposition = 
    DependencyProperty.Register("PinGeoposition", typeof(BasicGeoposition), typeof(CustomMapControl), null);

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
void SetValueDp(DependencyProperty property, object value, [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] String p = null)
{
    ViewModel.SetMode(ECustomMapControlMode.Default);
    SetValue(property, value);
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p));
}
```

Use of my control:

```
<customControls:CustomMapControl Mode="ForImage" PinGeoposition="{Binding Geoposition, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="1"/>
```

Finally in the pages' ViewModel where I use my control I have:

```cs
public BasicGeoposition Geoposition
{
    get { return _geoposition; }
    set
    {
        if (Set(ref _geoposition, value))
        {
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Geoposition);
        }
    }
}
```

I expect that every change of Geoposition in ViewModel to be reflected in SetValueDp. Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you set up a *DataContext*? Have you debuged to see what happens in code? I suspect that *SetValueDp* is fired only when you create binding - set up dependency property after that normal binding works.

Comment: I set DataContext in xaml file because my control is based on ViewModel. SetValueDp is never fired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what Jerry Nixon was trying to do on his blog article, as he didn't assign his `SetValueDp` method anywhere.

If you want it to be called, you can do something like that:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty PropertyPinGeoposition = 
DependencyProperty.Register("PinGeoposition", typeof(BasicGeoposition), typeof(CustomMapControl), new PropertyMetadata(null, SetPosition));

public BasicGeoposition PinGeoposition 
{ 
    get { return (BasicGeoposition) GetValue(PropertyPinGeoposition); } 
    set { SetValue(PropertyPinGeoposition, value);}
}

private static void SetPosition(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var control = (CustomMapControl)sender;

    var position = e.NewValue as BasicGeoposition;

    // Do whatever
}
```

---

**Edit:** After reading and re-reading the blog article, I think I got it backwards (and so did you, probably). From what I now understand, `SetValueDp` is a helper method you're supposed to call whenever you want to change the value of the dependency property. This is not something called automatically. So if you want a method that is called whenever the DP is modified, check my solution instead.

Comment: Seems like Jerry calls *SetValueDp* in PinGeoposition's setter - he exchanged SetValue with it.

Comment: @Romasz Well spotted. That said, the setter is called only when trying to update the property manually, not from a binding. So I guess @pbalut still needs to use `PropertyMetadata` for his use-case

Comment: How should looks like my PinGeoposition in code-behind ?
        `public BasicGeoposition PinGeoposition
        {
            get { return (BasicGeoposition) GetValue(PropertyPinGeoposition); }
            set { SetValue(PropertyPinGeoposition, value);}
        }` ?

Comment: @KooKiz Yup. The setter will be fired only once during initialization and then as you have mentioned when manually fired. OP can put some code as in your answer in *PropertyMetadata* or just in property setter as it seems to be two way bound - though everything depends on his needs.

Comment: @pbalut Yup, that's it. I've edited the answer and renamed the callback to `SetPosition`, to avoid any confusion with the `DependencyObject.SetValue` method (the one you're calling in the setter)

Comment: It works only after remove DataContext from UserControl. In my case it looks like: `DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=CustomMapControl}"` Exist any way to resolve it ?

Comment: @pbalut Where exactly are you setting the DataContext?

Comment: I use MVVM Light and the I'm setting the DataContext on the end of open tag ControlPanel in xaml file.

Comment: @pbalut You're not supposed to change the datacontext from inside the control. The page is responsible for creating the control's VM, set the appropriate values, and assign it to the control's datacontext

Comment: Do you suggest that I should remove ViewModel from my UserControl delivered by MVVM Light locator ?

Comment: @pbalut Yup. For pages, a VM locator is useful because their lifetime is handled by the navigation service. For custom controls, you're the one who creates and destroys them (through the page that hosts them), so you should create and assign the VM yourself. VM that can be exposed through a property of your page's VM, for instance.

Comment: What is the best way to call non-static method in SetPosition ?

Comment: @pbalut You have an instance of your control (see my code snippet). So simply do: `control.Method();`